# Using nbsp through style and not nbsp in HTML

Tags: html, css

Is there some style that I could apply so that instead of

```
<span style="color:hsl(255,100%,50%)">a&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;a</span>
```

I could use this?

```
<span style="color:hsl(255,100%,50%)">a    a</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is.

```
white-space: pre;
```